# Not able to get response on notify URL

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I just integrate paypal to my site
All is working good
Add product , Payment , then back to success page
but the only problem is notify_URL not works
I add mail function to test response but didnt get any mail

```
echo '<form target="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

         <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sendbox@creativemediafx.com">

         <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
         <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">

         <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://go4qp.com/fbtest/s1.php" />
         <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.urbaniacs.com/hideout/inventory/" />

         <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="'. $custom .'">
         <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="'. $itemnumber .'">          

         <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="' . $item->name . '">
         <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'. number_format($item->price,2) .'">
         <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

         <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_SM.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
         <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
         </form>';
```

Comment: try adding the mail function to your `return` page

Answer (score 0):

try adding the mail function to your return page ([IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/))

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.urbaniacs.com/hideout/inventory/" />
```

your `notify_url` will only work if you come back to your site manually after completing the payment process whereas the IPN will work instantly, also check if your mail function is working properly and on `return` URL dont use any sessions.